# Script to auto-replace a part of material settings

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, materials, transparency

I have a scene with hundreds of objects and materials. Some are with transparent masks (like leaves) and the other's none. Now I have a new material node setup and want to replace the "color" part of all the materials with this new setup while keep their transparent masks the same. I have try the materials option in RenderLayer but that does not work since the new material should not override the transparency mask of each object. I am thinking of writing a script, but do not know how and where to start.

If it is possible, can we automate the rendering pipeline to render the scene once with the original materials and once with the new one? Bash script is more desirable.

Comment: I'm not sure it is reasonable to expect people to write the script for you (particularly when the script will be very specific to your needs, as opposed to something that many people will find useful), rather it is better if you try to write it yourself and ask specific questions here when you get stuck (even if it is at the first hurdle).

Comment: I am sorry if my poor writing made you think so. I am looking for direction and instruction to do it, not asking anyone to write it for me.

Comment: So is the core of your question "How to render a scene multiple times with different materials?" If it is, I suggest changing the title and focusing the question on that.